# Use build-number as nuget-package-version

Tags: build, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, bamboo

I'm using bamboo to create nuget-packages with msbuild. Currenly I always have to bump the nuget-package-version by hand before commmitting code to git (where it gets automatically build).

I now want to use bamboo's build-number as version for the nuget-package.

Can I change the nuget-package-version with a command-line-tool?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can using Powershell. I haven't tested the script, but it should do the job. You need to define the version number in you nuspec as $version$ and then update that during build time. This way you would also be able to update other information.

```
function Update-NuspecVersion {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$RootFolder = $(throw "Repo folder is mandatory, please provide a value."),

    [Parameter()]
    [int]$BuildNumber
)

$Nuspecs  = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Recurse  -Filter *.nuspec | Where-Object { $_.FullName -notlike "*\obj\*"}
Foreach ($Nuspec in $Nuspecs) {
    $nuspecfile = [xml]$(Get-Content $Nuspec.FullName)
    $PackageVersion = $([xml]$(Get-Content $Nuspec.FullName) | % package).metadata.version
    if ($PackageVersion -eq '$version$') {  
        $Assembly = get-childitem $nuspec.Directory -Recurse -Filter "AssemblyInfo.Version.cs"
        if ($Assembly.Count -eq 0) {
            $Assembly = get-childitem $nuspec.Directory -Recurse -Filter "AssemblyInfo.cs"
        }
        $PackageVersion = $(Get-content $Assembly.FullName | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\/\/.+', ""; } | Select-String "AssemblyVersion").ToString().Split('"')[1]
    }

    $PackageVersionObject=[version]$PackageVersion
    if ($Branch.Type -eq "develop") {
        $PackageVersion ="{0}.{1}.{2}-{3}-{4}" -f $PackageVersionObject.major, $PackageVersionObject.Minor,  $BuildNumber, $Branch.Type, ("{0:D4}" -f  $BuildNumber) 
    }
    else {
        $PackageVersion ="{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $PackageVersionObject.major, $PackageVersionObject.Minor,  $BuildNumber
    }

    $nuspecfile.package.metadata.version = $PackageVersion
    $nuspecfile.Save($Nuspec.FullName)
}
}
```